# Create a Mainframe COMP-3 fields using Oracle SQL

Tags: mainframe, comp-3

I must send a file from Oracle DB to a IBM Mainframe machine and I must create some COMP-3 fields.

Usually I find some messages on how to read COMP-3 in Oracle, but I didn't find someone that had created it.

Is there someone that have create COMP-3 fields via TOAD SQL please ?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Denis

Comment: My suggestion: don't! Create a text-file, transfer as text and add a SORT-step on the mainframe to do the type-conversion for the COMP-3 fields. If you would somehow manage to create COMP-3 fields note that you would also have to encode all text as EBCDIC and transfer the file as binary.

Comment: I can't... the gov. company must receive the file with already COMP-3 :-(
Yes I know that I will must convert it using EBCDIC, but this I think will be more easy to do.
Thanks for the ideea :-)

Comment: I downloaded "gnu cobol" and I have make a cobol program that make me the COP-3 fields... in this mode I have solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded "GNU COBOL" and I have make a COBOL program that make me the COMP-3 fields... in this mode I have solved :-)